# How to install pkill on amazonlinux?

Tags: amazon-linux

Trying to install `pkill` on amazonlinux 2 doesn't work:

```
yum install -y pkill
...
No package pkill available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

and my favourite search engine hasn't helped, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

`pkill` is part of the `procps` package - this may be obvious to many but was the vital missing link which I didn't realise.

So this does the trick:

```
yum install -y procps
```

After this `pkill`, `pgrep`, `ps`, `watch` and more are now available on amazonlinux.

Comment: "_`pkill` is part of the `procps` package_", right, as `yum provides pkill` would state.

Comment: That's good to know! Being new to yum this was not something I was aware of. Hopefully it helps someone else as un-knowledgeable as me in future :)